# How to map native sql results to oneToMany field with SqlResultSetMapping in JPA

Tags: java, sql, jpa

For example, say I have the following database tables

```
Building
-----------
id
name
```

and

```
Room
-----------
id
roomNo
buildingId
```

the Building Java class will look something like

```
@Entity
public class Building {       
   private int id;
   @OneToMany private List<Room> rooms;
...
```

I have the following SQL to fetch Building

```sql
SELECT   b.id,
         b.name,
         r.id AS rid,
         r.roomNo 
FROM     Building b
  LEFT JOIN Room r ON
         b.id = r.buildingId
```

the result will be

```
id, name, rid, roomNo
---------------------
1, 'b1', 10, 'r100'
1, 'b1', 11, 'r101'
2, 'b2', 12, 'r10'
```

Note that there are duplicate Building due to one-to-many relationship.

I know that I can get the Building entity simply by using JPQL but I want to do this with native SQL. So how would I map the result above back to the Building class using JPA's @SqlResultSetMapping?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this program? I'm afraid I have been resorting to sub-par solutions to meet deadlines.

Comment: I don't think this is possible in JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code if you want to keep the Join statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         b.id,
         b.name,
         0 AS rid,
         '' AS roomNo 

FROM     Building b
  LEFT JOIN Room r ON
         b.id = r.buildingId
```